# Django deploy with Heroku for the first time

Tags: django, heroku, deployment

My first time deploying an app, I'm following the PrettyPrinted video "Deploy a Django App to Heroku". Whell, when I ran `heroku local` I'm get this error.

```
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.52.0 to 7.53.1.
[WARN] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Procfile'
[FAIL] No Procfile and no package.json file found in Current Directory - See run --help
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at Index.run (/snap/heroku/4048/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-local/lib/commands/local/index.js:30:38)
    at Index._run (/snap/heroku/4048/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-local/node_modules/@oclif/command/lib/command.js:43:31)
```

My project look like this:

[image: My project schema]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rename ProcFile to Procfile. Heroku can't find this file.